# Marketing Cloud API changes

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

So, just today as I was looking at the [SOAP API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/web_service_guide.htm), I found the following message:

> Marketing Cloud has a new model for storing, finding, managing,
>   creating, sharing, and distributing all content-related objects.
>   Access the objects created with the new Content Builder tools using
>   the REST API. Your existing SOAP API integrations only function with
>   the Classic tools in the user interface.

Are you guys aware of what the phrase `Your existing SOAP API integrations only function with the Classic tools in the user interface.` implies? I don't really understand what's really being deprecated and what not.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the service reference that I'm using in my VS project and I found a lot of changes. But, It seems SOAP service is still running with the new changes.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP API only works on emails inside the original Email Studio tool - called 'Classic Content' (You can switch between these platforms in Email Studio on the top right of the left frame - where the folder structure is).

This was the default platform pre-2014 Beta of Content Builder/Content Canvas (which eventually became just Content Builder). At the 2016 Connections, this was officially released and became the default editor for all.

No capabilities were lost from the content currently in Classic Content in this transition. This only affected the newly created content in Content Builder.

The reason no SOAP objects worked on Content Builder content was because it was stored in a completely different location in a completely different way. This made it impossible to fit into the existing SOAP API methodology.

To help make this new platform more future facing, they built a REST API call structure to interact with the content there. ([referenced here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/content-api.htm))

This REST API is not as robust in capability as the SOAP was, but it continues to grow and allows you more versatility through interaction in many of the other new features and platforms that SOAP does not (e.g. Mobile Connect and Journey Builder).

Comment: Recently our WSDL stopped working, that's why we ended up here... and I don't really understand it. We had to update the web service.

Comment: have you verified you are using the secure gateway (https instead of http) as the insecure gateway is no longer supported. List of WSDL links here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api.htm